# Querying Azure Log Analytics from C# application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-log-analytics

I am struggling for the past few days to query custom logs from Azure Log Analytics. I've been following the tutorial provided by Microsoft from https://dev.int.loganalytics.io/documentation/1-Tutorials/Direct-API but I keep getting 403. I granted all permission on the workspace to my Azure Application
[![Azure Application permissions on the ALA Workspace][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxT2A.png
Here is a simple application code I am using to try to query ALA Workspace

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        String tenantId = "??????????????????????????????????";
        String applicationId = "??????????????????????????????????";";
        String applictionSecretKey = "??????????????????????????????????";;
        String token;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Dictionary<String, String> requestData = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            requestData.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            requestData.Add("client_id", applicationId);
            requestData.Add("client_secret", applictionSecretKey);
            requestData.Add("resource", "https://api.loganalytics.io/");
            FormUrlEncodedContent requestBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestData);

            var request = await client.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token", requestBody);
            var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response).access_token;

        }

        String workspaceId = "??????????????????????????????????";;

        String query = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            query = "ApplicationLog_CL | take 10",
            timespan = "PT12H"
        });
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            var postContent = new StringContent(query, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/query", postContent);

            HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(content);

        }



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I keep getting 403 response from ALA API. Any clue what I am missing here?

Comment: Any process now?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [tutorial](https://dev.int.loganalytics.io/documentation/1-Tutorials/Direct-API) you provided, I test in my site and it works very well.

Here are some ways you could troubleshooting.

1.When you `add role` in `Access control`, you could add the AAD registered app which name is `AIDemoApp` like tutorial.

[image]

And the Log Analytics API permission is add in AAD.
[image]

2.Change `new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")` to `new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`.

3.After adding Permission in the registered app in AAD, click `Grant Permission`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joey, still having same problem, not really getting what is wrong. Let you know if I manage to make anything work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the string content

```
var postContent = new StringContent(query, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Log analytics API is expecting the charset to be empty

Add the below line to make it work.

```
postContent.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = string.Empty;
```